# why i am getting SIGCONT, it's running in some IDE'S

Tags: c++, c++14

I am solving a practice problem from codechef problemcode:RECIPE

Firstly I tried with array instead of vector but I got the same error

```
    int n;
    int flag=0,x=0;
    vector <int> v;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
        v.push_back(a[i]);
    }
    sort(a,a+n);
    x=a[0];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        if (a[i]%x!=0)
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    vector<int>::iterator p;
    if (flag==0)
        for (p=v.begin(); p<v.end(); p++)
            cout<<*p/x<<" ";
    else for (p=v.begin(); p<v.end(); p++)
            cout<<*p<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
```

This code is working in my IDE but it's giving runtime error on codechef IDE

Comment: For input: `n = 1, a[0] = 0`, you divide by zero in `*p/x`, because default value of `flag` is `0`.

Comment: thanks i got it @rafix07